# Синтаксическая ошибка в условном выражении

Tags: javascript

Вот написал такую функцию, основанную на if:

```
function randomIMG() {

var tmpnum = Math.random();

if (tmpnum < 0.25) { 
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k.png'); 
}

else { 
    if (tmpnum >= 0.25 && tmpnum < 0.50) { 
        return('http://tervueren.ru/k2.png'); 
        } 
    }

else { 
    if (tmpnum => 0.50 && tmpnum < 0.75) {
        return('http://tervueren.ru/k3.png'); 
        } 
    }

else { 
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k3.png'); 
};

}
```

Хром выдал проблему:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
```

И указал на строчку со вторым else-ом

Comment: У вас три else подряд.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В if  может быть только один else:

```
function randomIMG() {

var tmpnum = Math.random();

if (tmpnum < 0.25) { 
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k.png'); 
}
else if (tmpnum >= 0.25 && tmpnum < 0.50) { 
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k2.png'); 
} else if (tmpnum => 0.50 && tmpnum < 0.75) {
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k3.png'); 
} else { 
    return('http://tervueren.ru/k3.png'); 
};
}
```